# Highcharts - dual-axes column chart not rendering the way it was a week ago

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

I have created a duel-axes column chart, columns side by side, and it was working great until yesterday.

Yesterday, it started rendering a stacked column graph instead of the columns showing side by side. After checking the highcharts examples on their website, I realized that theirs are also rendering this way now.

Any thoughts on how to get the columns to be side by side again?

Here is an image of what I see in FF and Chrome:

Here is the js from highcharts.com (http://jsfiddle.net/d4GfS/):

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average Monthly Temperature and Rainfall in Tokyo'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value}°C',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} mm',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Rainfall',
            color: '#4572A7',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mm'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Temperature',
            color: '#89A54E',
            type: 'column',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: The jsFiddle you link to renders side by side for me.

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you cleared your cache recently? Mine was also rendering side by side and some of my users complained that it had changed. I cleared my cache, and I to was seeing them stacked...

Comment: Stacked for me in Chrome.

Comment: I do not want it to stack. I am looking for it to be side to side. Any ideas how to do that? It used to show that way...until very recently.

Comment: Would one of you please try clearing your cache and then reloading? I found that before I did that it rendered fine, after it did not. Thank you.

Comment: It's a bug, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2086). Thanks! Right now you need to downgrade to 3.0.2 to get rid off that bug.